# How do I extract undefined global variables using ANTLR V4

Tags: javascript, java, python, antlr, antlr4

I have a Python grammar and a textbox where users can write simple python expressions, such as this one:

```
(lambda x: str(x))(wanted_input)
```

The expression is then injected with wanted_input (by using an artificial context created when we execute the python expr).

I am interested if it is possible to use Parse Tree Listeners to extract *wanted_input* which are basically undefined global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

I believe there are exactly three types of expressions that can introduce new variable names: lambdas, list comprehensions and generator comprehensions. So in your listener or visitor, you'll want to add the newly introduced variables to the current scope when entering these three types of expressions and then remove them again when exiting (making sure to handle the case where a variable is shadowed - some kind of stack is usually the tool of choice here). Then when you see a variable, you simply check whether it's defined in the current scope. If not, it's one of the variables you want to extract.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any quick tips on how to determine if you entered a list comprehensions or generator comprehensions?

Comment: @user3642381 I don't know what your grammar looks like, but usually you'd know that you're entering a list comprehension because `enterListComprehension` has been called. If the listener generated for your grammar only contains `enterExpression` and nothing more specific, you might want to add [alternative labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) to your grammar.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. This is the grammar I am using: https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/grammar.html - how would I go to extract variables? The only way I see it is to enterExpression and use regex. Is there any other way?

Comment: @user3642381 I meant the ANTLR grammar. I was saying that since I don't know whether your grammar contains alternative labels and, if so, what you called those labels, I don't know whether there will be a `enterListComprehension` method or that it's name will be exactly `enterListComprehension`.